# Do Dynamically-Generated Custom Tags Harm SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript

In my JavaScript file, I create a "fake" tag (Like this):

```
<fake-tag>
    <another-fake-tag></another-fake-tag>
    <self_closing-fake_tag />
</fake-tag>
```

These tags generated when the script is called, and not part of the website itself.

```
(function() {
    // ...
    let e = document.createElement("fake-tag");
    document.body.parentNode.appendChild(e);
    // Refer to the tag...
    e = document.querySelector("fake-tag");
    e.innerHTML = "<self_closing-fake_tag />";
    // ...
})();
```

Can it harm the SEO of the website?

Comment: I guess no answers means no, but I decided to stick to the HTML rules and I won't invent my own tags (even though, I must admit, it will make my life easier). Thanks anyways...

Comment: What is the purpose of the fake tags?   Have you done testing in lots of browsers? Last time I checked some browsers treated unknown tags differently than others.

Comment: I haven't tested. to me they worked well (and actually the same) in all major browsers (except for Safari which I don't have) but I decided to go with the "better safe than sorry" way until someone will help me to verify that I can use them without worrying about SEO

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The purpose is to insert them before body in order to apply styles to the body which can affect these tags

Comment: For styling you should use `<div class=foo>` rather than `<foo>`.